# OperationTimeout /WriteTimeOut on Await Duration.Inf

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka

I am looking at some code where data is written to cassandra using

```
Await.result(casDB.store(someVal), Duration.Inf)
```

I am seeing OperationTimeoutException and WriteTimeoutException. Say if we had 5 seconds timeout and server didnt respond within 5 second then i can think of these exception. But when duration is set to Inf not able to understand what is the reason for these exception.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that Duration.inf it’s the duration for which control blocks for the Future to be completed. Write time exception cause because of various reason like too many writes or consistency level of your query. What is the default consistency level for your query?

Comment: consistency level is LOCAL_QUORUM

Comment: and how many nodes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration named `reference.conf` in the `akka.jar`. The default timeout for akka is `5` seconds.

So you should create a new configuration and named it `application.conf`. set `actor->typed->timeout = 3000s`